# How to dynamically set value in mysql query from an object?

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, mariadb

I am trying to have an abstract method that can handle any update to a particular table. I want this to pull and set dynamically without using any additional code logic.

I know of a few ways to accomplish this, either using addition code logic or just refining the query to be more explicit.

```
let result = await db.query(`UPDATE media SET ? WHERE product_id=?;`, [[data.variant_id], productId]);
return result;
}
```

I would like to have the `set` value be, in this case, variant_id=.

I don't know of a way to accomplish this in the query itself other than setting the value prior to the query

Comment: I do know that this can be accomplished by just setting the value in the object and using the set ? and passing the object through, I just want to know if there is a way to do this dynamically within mysql.query format.

Comment: More of what I was looking for is as follows let newValue = { [property]: value }; let result = await db.query('UPDATE media SET ? WHERE product_id=?;',[newValue, productId]); return result;

Answer (score 0):

You missed the column  name

```
  let result = await db.query('UPDATE media SET your_column_name =  ? 
  WHERE product_id=?;',
        [[data.variant_id], productId]);
```

and don't use backtics for sql string use single quote instead  .. In mysql backtics are  used  for composite column name and column name containing reserved  word

Answer (score 0):

Use the prepare statement for Mysql dynamic update fields

```
set @stmt = concat ("UPDATE media SET  variant_id=",data," WHERE product_id=",productId," ;");
prepare resultset from @stmt;
execute resultset;
deallocate prepare resultset;
```